# Want python return data before async function completes

Tags: python, asynchronous

What can I write to achieved the desired effect?

Desired printing: 1 (nap func started here) 2 (99 returned here) 3

```
import asyncio

async def nap():
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    print(3)

async def main():
    print(1)
    
    #I don't want to wait for func nap to complete. I just want nap to start here and finish the sleep after '2' is printed. Is that possible?
    await nap()
    print(2)
    return 99

# Python 3.7+
asyncio.run(main())
```

Currently prints:
1 (nap func started here) 3 2 (99 returned here)

Comment: `asyncio.ensure_future(nap())` and then *not* `await` that… but in this particular case, that would result in a terminated future, since nothing else is awaiting the completion of `nap`, if you require `main` to *return* before it's finished…

Comment: Indeed I want `main` to return 99 *before* nap is finished. Is there no other way around, like Threading etc.?

Comment: You could define `main` as an async generator, this way it can yield a value then await its sub-routine, then return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def nap():
    print('Nap started...')
    time.sleep(4)
    print(3)

def main():
    print(1)
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
    task1 = executor.submit(nap)
    print(2)
    return 99

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_returned_before_tasks_complete = main()
    print('data_returned_before_tasks_complete: ', data_returned_before_tasks_complete)
```